# Zeta function product in Amann and Escher

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

The following text is taken from *Analysis II* by Amann and Escher, p. 61:

> We denote the sequence of prime numbers by $(p_k)$ [...]. It therefore follows for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$ that
> $$\prod_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{1-p_k^{-s}}=\prod_{k=1}^m \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p_k^{js}}=\sum '\frac{1}{n^s}$$
> where, after “multiplying out”, the series contains all numbers of the form $\frac{1}{n^s}$,
> whose prime factor decomposition $n=$[...] has no other prime numbers from$p_1,\ldots ,p_m$. Therefore $\sum '(1/n^s)$ indeed contains all numbers $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\le p_m$. The
> absolute convergence of the series $\sum_n (1/n^s)$ then implies
> $$\left|\zeta (s)-\prod_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{1-p_k^{-s}}\right|=\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}-\sum '\frac{1}{n^s}\right|\le \sum_{n\gt p_m}\frac{1}{n^{\operatorname{Re}s}}.$$
> From [...] (a theorem of Euclid), it follows that $p_m\to\infty$ for $m\to\infty$. Therefore, from [the fact that $\sum 1/n^s$ converges absolutely...], the remaining series $\left(\sum_{n\gt p_m} (1/n^{\operatorname{Re}s})\right)$ is a null sequence.

And this is the supposed end of the proof of Euler's product formula for the zeta function.

**Question**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746532/proof-of-infinitude-of-primes-by-eulers-product-formula-is-circular) is about supposed circularity in proving that the number of primes is infinite by Euler's product formula. The conclusion there is that no circularity is involved. But I was looking for a rigorous proof of Euler's product formula and, as it seems, it *uses* infitude of primes (see "it follows that $p_m\to\infty$ for $m\to\infty$ "). Or am I missing something?

**Edit:**
The proof number 3 [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/riemann-zeta-function/) (*Euler Product Representation*) uses the geometric series argument (as Amann does), yet it doesn't seem to use the infitude primes. Is the infitude of primes in Amann's proof superfluous? I'm really confused.

Comment: The "therefore" in the second sentence doesn't follow unless we write say "We denote the [unlimited or infinite] sequence of prime numbers [e.g. already proved by Euclid] by ($p_k$) [...]. It therefore follows for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$ that.."

Comment: @JamesArathoon That's perhaps a subtle point. But the book *Gamma* from Havil (pages 61, 62) uses essentialy the same argument (see the geometric series at the beginning, then multiplying everything out...) to prove the infitude of primes (since $\zeta (2)$ is irrational) which I'm a bit concerned about: these arguments just seem circular.

Comment: As far as I see it the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is proved for finite "positive integers" $>1$ only, and by direct implication the finite set of all the finite "positive integers" $>1$. In the partial summation for $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^s}$ we require the counting numbers up to arbitrary large $n$. How do we know that the set of positive integers consistent with the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (adding the number 1) and the set of positive counting numbers up to any arbitrary large $n$, are equivalent?

Comment: Introducing the infinite set of Natural Numbers a priori to solve this problem of linking the two seems less than ideal to me.

Comment: @JamesArathoon I'm not quite sure if I understand your comment correctly, but clearly there's no problem with FTA at all, but rather with Amann's proof "seemingly requiring" the infitude of primes. I found a very similar proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Another_proof). There is "Taking all the primes $p$ up to some *prime number limit* $q$, we have"... Is it required that $q$ be a prime number? Is it required that the limit $q$ be infinite?

Comment: "Taking all the [distinct] primes $p$ up to some [arbitrary large] prime number limit $q$, we have"  How do you know that the "distinct" primes don't run out at some arbitrary large limit?

Comment: @JamesArathoon Well, I don't know why the Wikipedia proof requires $q$ to be prime (the same goes for Amann). If the product is over $p\le q+1$ instead of over $p\le q$ (if $q\gt 2$ is prime then $q+1$ is not) then the value of the product is left unchanged. Also, do you mean the primes have to be distinct? Why? (we're not supposed to arrive at a contradiction proving the infitude of primes right now, but just to prove that the zeta product has to be $\prod \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ and run over all primes, whether or not the set of primes is infinite)

Comment: @JamesArathoon Knowing that we can always find an integer which is greater than a given prime should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I been thinking about this a lot and the question put is both subtle and non-trivial. As you have indicated, mathematicians in the published literature are coming to different conclusions on this question which is disconcerting.

The provisional conclusion I've come to (at least in general philosophical/logical terms) is this.

I think that mathematicians are logically obliged to prove that there is a fundamental core consistency to a proposed theory of numbers based on on an agreed set of definitions, axioms and laws and fundamental theorems on primes etc., before utilising a proof by contradiction that effectively begs the question (in this case on the existence of the said core consistency to the theory of numbers before it is actually proved/demonstrated).

Begging the question is a form of circular reasoning, which in some cases can lead to logical fallacies.

This answer goes against the majority of answers to the question you linked to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746532/proof-of-infinitude-of-primes-by-eulers-product-formula-is-circular).