# Proof of Euler's product for $\zeta (s)$ without using infinitude of primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, special-functions, riemann-zeta

There are two proofs of
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}=\prod_{p\,\text{prime}}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}},\quad \Re (s)\gt 1$$
which I'm aware of. I'll call the first one the **Sieve proof** and the second one will be the **Factorization proof**. Both of them use infinitude of primes.

1. Sieve proof

By sieving, we see that for every prime $q$
$$\left(\prod_{p\,\text{prime}\le q}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)\right)\zeta (s)=\sum_{n;2,3,\ldots ,q\nshortmid n}\frac{1}{n^s},\quad \Re (s)\gt 1$$
where the sum is over all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that are not divisible by the primes from $2$ to $q$. Choosing $r\gt 1$ such that $|s|\gt r$ gives
$$\begin{align}\left|\left(\prod_{p\,\text{prime}\le q}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)\right)\zeta (s)-1\right|&=\left|\sum_{n;n\ne 1 \& 2,3,\ldots q,\nshortmid n}\frac{1}{n^s}\right|\\
&\le \sum_{n;n\ne 1 \& 2,3,\ldots q,\nshortmid n}\frac{1}{n^r}\\
&\le \sum_{n=q}^\infty \frac{1}{n^r},\quad \Re (s)\gt 1.\end{align}$$
**Because of infinitude of primes**, we can let $q\to\infty$, and by Cauchy's criterion for series $\lim_{q\to\infty}\sum_{n=q}^\infty \frac{1}{n^r}=0$, so
$$\left(\prod_{p\,\text{prime}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)\right)\zeta (s)=1,\quad \Re (s)\gt 1.$$

2. Factorization proof (this proof is taken from *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-function* by Titchmarsh)

We have
$$\prod_{p\le P}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^s}+\frac{1}{p^{2s}}+\cdots\right)=1+\frac{1}{n_1^s}+\frac{1}{n_2^s}+\cdots$$
where $n_1,n_2,\ldots$ are those integers none of whose prime factors exceed $P$. It follows that
$$\begin{align}\left|\zeta (s)-\prod_{p\le P}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}\right|&=\left|\zeta (s)-1-\frac{1}{n_1^s}-\frac{1}{n_2^s}-\cdots\right|\\
&\le \frac{1}{(P+1)^{\Re (s)}}+\frac{1}{(P+2)^{\Re (s)}}+\cdots\end{align}$$
This tends to $0$ as $P\to\infty$ (again **using infinitude of primes**) if $\Re (s)\gt 1$ and the product formula follows.

This led me to the following question: Is there a proof of Euler's product for $\zeta (s)$ without using infinitude of primes? Note that this is not a duplicate of [Proof of Infinitude of Primes by Euler's Product Formula is Circular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746532/proof-of-infinitude-of-primes-by-eulers-product-formula-is-circular) because the OP there fails to distinguish between the fundamental theorem of arithmetic and infinitude of primes.

Comment: $\sum_{1,\cdots,q\,{\large\nmid} \,n}\frac{1}{n^s}$ is the empty sum if $1,\cdots,q$ includes all the primes, right?

Comment: Are you sure both of these proofs assume there are infinitely many primes, as opposed to squeezing series defined in terms of $q,\,P$?

Comment: @J.G. What squeezing series are you talking about? I'd be happy for a proof which doesn't use infinitude of primes. If you know one, please post it as an answer.

Comment: What I mean is the sieve proof only needs $\sum_{n\ge q}n^{-r}\le\int_{q-1}^\infty x^{-r}dx=(q-1)^{1-r}/(r-1)$, which $\to0$ as $q\to\infty$, whereas the factorization proof can do likewise replacing $q,\,r$ with $P+1,\,\Re(s)$. It's got nothing to do with how many primes there are.

Comment: @J.G. I see. But I don't quite understand what you mean "replacing $q,r$ with $P+1,\Re (s)$." Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @J.G And regarding the sieve proof: Didn't we assume that $q$ is prime at the beginning?

Comment: There's no need to assume that.

Comment: @J.G. And if I understand correctly, we don't assume that $P$ is prime in the factorization proof either?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145159/discussion-between-vestoo-and-j-g).

Comment: @J.G. Your comments contradict a textbook by Amann and Escher (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165001/zeta-function-product-in-amann-and-escher) and a Wikipedia proof (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Another_proof) – notice that they use "up to some **prime number limit $q$**.", then they let $q\to\infty$.